# Detect Automated Sign ups for Ruby on Rails webapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security, automation, passenger

I have been googling for the past few hours for this but could not manage to find anything relevant. The idea is inspired from Quora which does not ask for captcha during sign up but I guess using other detection methods, presumably frequent requests from the same IP address to counter fake account creations through bots. Is there a rails gem or setting in phusion passenger that can be done to have the same functionality?

At a broader level what is the viability of a gem which allows you to set up individual frequency of calls to various actions across the web app based on parameters such as ip address, email, user id etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about using https://github.com/joshfrench/rakismet ?

It use akismet service to check spam.